# preload next and previous slides

Tags: javascript

I'm using this simple slideshow [link](http://en.gg/increase-pageviews-multi-page-slideshows), it works fine but I would like to preload previous and next slides to make slideshow faster.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Show us your code, and you have tried

Comment: The link you are providing triggers a full page load on each click (usual slideshows are contained in one page. That "trick" is to increase the number of page views for the same user). 
Are you asking how to cache image so that on the next page load they are already cached by the browser?

Comment: @LinoLinux Yes I chose this slideshow to increase page views, and I am looking for a way to cache images of the next and previous slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are served with the correct [`Cache Control` header](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) and if they have subsequent names (like image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg, image_3.jpg) you can try to load them in the current page.

With jQuery, `$("<img />").attr("src", "image_1.jpg");` allows you to load an image without putting it into the DOM. You can use it to load next and previous image according to current image.

Comment: Thank you @LinoLinux, the image are loaded successfully into current page, but how do I check if my images are served with the correct Cache Control header ?

Comment: If you're not sure, access the Developer Tools of your browser and check for the headers of the delivered resources. In this page, for example, your avatar has (for my last request) `cache-control:max-age=1209600, no-transform` and `expires:Sun, 13 Sep 2015 12:12:29 GMT`

Comment: Ok, these are my images header details :
Cache-control: max-age=2592000
Expires:Fri, 02 Oct 2015 17:40:53 GMT
Thank you @LinoLinux